# Android dynamic range compression java fft

Tags: android

I want dynamic range compression java fft die volume control. Who had exprience with this on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help - but I've been searching for compander apps for Android - lots of material with low passages that need amplification, without blowing my ears out on other passages.
I found a company that has an SDK that sounds very interesting - SuperPower
SuperPowered... http://superpowered.com/audio-compressor-limiter-and-clipper-for-android-and-ios-superpowered-audio-engine-update 
Not that this will help me -- I forgot all of my FFT/discrete time systems college stuff a couple decades ago, and I am in no position to roll my own - but maybe it will help you.